# How can I calculate magnetic field strength from latitude longitude?

Tags: magnetic-fields

How can I calculate magnetic field strength from any given latitude longitude?

Comment: The answer to this varies depending on the precision you want, from "just use a magnetic dipole" on the least precise end to "just look up the data and don't bother calculating it" on the most precise end.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth's field is not something you calculate from scratch. Instead, go to the National Geodetic Data Center and use their calculator:

https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/magfield.shtml

Now the gravity field is stored as spherical harmonic coefficients that can be downloaded along with Fortran code to compute the values, or the data can be downloaded as a grid and interpolated as needed.

A similar protocol is available for the International Geomagnetic Reference Field:

https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/IAGA/vmod/igrf.html

Comment: I need the data as a service or as a table though as I am looking to use it an app.

Comment: I found it here: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/thirdpartycontributions.shtml